# Rational rank one decomposition of symmetric positive semidefinite integer matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

> **Problem**: Given an $n\times n$ symmetric positive semidefinite (PSD) $\color{blue}{\textbf{integer}}$ matrix $Q$ with $\mathrm{Rank}(Q) = r$, find
> $\color{blue}{\textbf{integer}}$ vectors $u_i, i=1, \cdots, r$ and
> positive $\color{blue}{\textbf{integer}}$ pairs $(c_i, d_i), i=1, \cdots, r$ such that $$Q = \frac{c_1}{d_1} u_1u_1^\mathsf{T} + 
> \frac{c_2}{d_2} c_2u_2 u_2^\mathsf{T} + \cdots + \frac{c_r}{d_r} u_r u_r^\mathsf{T}.$$

**Background**:

The problem arises when we express a non-negative polynomial as a sum of squares (SOS) of polynomials.
See e.g. https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/sos_slides.pdf.
When we get $f(x) = Z(x)^\mathsf{T}Q Z(x)$ (see page 8 in the link above), we hope to do rational rank one decomposition of $Q$
such that we can express $f(x)$ as sum of squares of polynomials that is $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^r [f_i(x)]^2$.

Also see my answers for the following questions:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193753/this-inequality-why-cant-solve-it-by-now-only-four-variables-inequality,
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239243/an-inequality-concerning-lagranges-identity

**Discussion**:

This task is easy by the following fact:

*Fact 1*: Let $B$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. Let $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector
such that $u^\mathsf{T}Bu \ne 0$, then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Rank}\left(B - \frac{1}{u^\mathsf{T}Bu} Buu^\mathsf{T}B\right) &= \mathrm{Rank}(B) - 1, \tag{1}\\
B - \frac{1}{u^\mathsf{T}Bu} Buu^\mathsf{T}B &\succeq 0. \tag{2}
\end{align}
For (1), see Theorem 1.1 in [1]. (2) is obvious.

According to Fact 1, we have the following process:

First we choose any integer vector $v_1$ such that $v_1^\mathsf{T}Qv_1 \ne 0$,
let $Q_1 = Q - \frac{1}{v_1^\mathsf{T}Qv_1} Qv_1v_1^\mathsf{T}Q$.

Second, choose any integer vector $v_2$ such that $v_2^\mathsf{T}Q_1v_2 \ne 0$,
let $Q_2 = Q_1 - \frac{1}{v_2^\mathsf{T}Q_1v_2}Q_1v_2v_2^\mathsf{T}Q_1$.

$\cdots\cdots$

Finally we get $Q = \frac{1}{v_1^\mathsf{T}Qv_1} Qv_1v_1^\mathsf{T}Q + \frac{1}{v_2^\mathsf{T}Q_1v_2}
Q_1v_2v_2^\mathsf{T}Q_1 + \cdots$.

**Example 1**:

$$Q = \left(\begin{array}{rrr} 16 & -17 & 12\\ -17 & 23 & -6\\ 12 & -6 & 19 \end{array}\right),$$
$v_1 = [1, 0, 0]^\mathsf{T}$,
$$Q_1 = \left(\begin{array}{rrr} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 79/16 & 27/4\\ 0 & 27/4 & 10 \end{array}\right),$$
$v_2 = [0, 1, 0]^\mathsf{T}$,
$$Q_2 = \left(\begin{array}{rrr} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 61/79 \end{array}\right).$$
Terminate since $\mathrm{Rank}(Q_2) = 1$. We have
$$Q = \frac{1}{16} u_1u_1^\mathsf{T} + \frac{1}{1264}u_2u_2^\mathsf{T} + \frac{61}{79}u_3u_3^\mathsf{T}$$
where
$u_1 = [16, -17, 12]^\mathsf{T}, u_2 = [0, 79, 108]^\mathsf{T},
u_3 = [0, 0, 1]^\mathsf{T}$.

**Example 2**: For the same $Q$ as Example 1, we choose different $v_1, v_2$.

$$Q = \left(\begin{array}{rrr} 16 & -17 & 12\\ -17 & 23 & -6\\ 12 & -6 & 19 \end{array}\right),$$
$v_1 = [2, 1, -1]^\mathsf{T}$,
$$Q_1 = \left(\begin{array}{rrr} 23/2 & -19/2 & 27/2\\ -19/2 & 21/2 & -17/2\\ 27/2 & -17/2 & 37/2 \end{array}\right),$$
$v_2 = [1, 0, -1]^\mathsf{T}$,
$$Q_2 = \left(\begin{array}{rrr} 61/6 & -61/6 & 61/6\\ -61/6 & 61/6 & -61/6\\ 61/6 & -61/6 & 61/6 \end{array}\right).$$
Terminate since $\mathrm{Rank}(Q_2) = 1$. We have
$$Q = \frac{1}{2} u_1u_1^\mathsf{T} + \frac{1}{3}u_2u_2^\mathsf{T} + \frac{61}{6}u_3u_3^\mathsf{T}$$
where
$u_1 = [3, -5, 1]^\mathsf{T}, u_2 = [-2, -1, -5]^\mathsf{T},
u_3 = [1, -1, 1]^\mathsf{T}$.

**Example 3**: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239243/an-inequality-concerning-lagranges-identity

$$Q = \left(\begin{array}{rrrr} 7942 & -4138 & 917 & -4721\\ -4138 & 7934 & -4717 & 921\\ 917 & -4717 & 6000 & -2200\\ -4721 & 921 & -2200 & 6000 \end{array}\right),$$
$v_1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]^\mathsf{T}$,
$$Q_1 = \left(\begin{array}{rrrr} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 22944392/3971 & -16833934/3971 & -6110458/3971\\ 0 & -16833934/3971 & 46811111/7942 & -13143243/7942
\\ 0 & -6110458/3971 & -13143243/7942 & 25364159/7942 \end{array}\right),$$
$v_2 = [0, 1, 0, 0]^\mathsf{T}$,
$$Q_2 = \left(\begin{array}{rrrr} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 7984289425/2868049 & -7984289425/2868049
\\ 0 & 0 & -7984289425/2868049 & 7984289425/2868049 \end{array}\right).$$
Terminate since $\mathrm{Rank}(Q_2) = 1$. We have
$$Q = \frac{1}{7942} u_1u_1^\mathsf{T} + \frac{1}{22778045158}u_2u_2^\mathsf{T} 
+ \frac{7984289425}{2868049}u_3u_3^\mathsf{T}$$
where
$u_1 = [7942, -4138, 917, -4721]^\mathsf{T}, u_2 = [0, 11472196, -8416967, -3055229]^\mathsf{T}$ and
$u_3 = [0, 0, 1, -1]^\mathsf{T}$.

**Question**:

From Examples 1-2, we see that the numbers ($c_i$'s, $d_i$'s, elements of $u_i$'s, in absolute value) in Example 2 is smaller than that in Example 1
which is due to different choice of $v_1, v_2$. We say the rank one decomposition in Example 2 is better.

From Example 3, we see that the numbers ($c_i$'s, $d_i$'s, elements of $u_i$'s, in absolute value) can be quite large (the biggest one is $22778045158$)
even when the numbers in $Q$ is not large (the biggest one is $7942$). Is there another $v_1, v_2$ such that
the numbers are much smaller?

One can imagine that when $n$ is large and $\mathrm{Rank}(Q)$ is large (e.g., $n>100$, I have ever encountered), the numbers may be very very large if we randomly choose $v_1, v_2, \cdots$.

Is there algorithms to find the better solution by nicely choosing $v_1, v_2, \cdots$?

Any comments and solutions are welcome and appreciated.

*Reference*

[1] Moody T. Chu, Robert E. Funderlic and Gene H. Golub, “A Rank-One Reduction Formula and its Applications to Matrix Factorizations”,
SIAM Review, Vol. 37, No. 4 (Dec., 1995), pp. 512-530.

Comment: Intuitively, it seems $v_1$ must be close to the singular vector of $Q$ corresponding to the smallest singular value. Did you try calculating the singular vectors of $Q$ ?

Comment: @Damien Thanks for comment. If that eigenvector (normalized) is $[0.622193101957268, -0.779207381418775, 0.0755751329200000]^\mathsf{T}$,
how to choose integer/rational $v_1$?

Comment: It's here@tthnew

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with rational symmetric $H,$   we may calculate a nonsingular rational $L$ such that $H = L D L^T$  with $D$ diagonal rational. Taking the diagonal elements $d_i$ of $D,$  we know $D = \sum d_i e_i e_i^T,$  where $e_i$ is the column vector with a single $1$ at position $i$ and otherwise $0.$  It follows that
$$ H = \sum  d_i L e_i e_i^T L^T = \sum d_i (Le_i) (Le_i)^T$$

There are two basic methods for diagonalizing a quadratic form. One may repeatedly complete the square, as in many quadratics forms books. Students seem to have trouble with that, although it has always seemed easy to me. The opposite method is suitable for computers, so I will put in output from my program.

for now, see [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

The matrix I call $L$ above becomes $L=Q^T$  in the output below

$$ \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 17 }{ 16 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 174 }{ 79 }  &  -  \frac{ 108 }{ 79 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 &  - 17 & 12 \\ 
 - 17 & 23 &  - 6 \\ 
12 &  - 6 & 19 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 17 }{ 16 }  &  -  \frac{ 174 }{ 79 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 108 }{ 79 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 79 }{ 16 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 61 }{ 79 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 17 }{ 16 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  \frac{ 108 }{ 79 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 79 }{ 16 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 61 }{ 79 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 17 }{ 16 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 108 }{ 79 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
16 &  - 17 & 12 \\ 
 - 17 & 23 &  - 6 \\ 
12 &  - 6 & 19 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2069 }{ 3971 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3060867 }{ 11472196 }  &  \frac{ 8416967 }{ 11472196 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
7942 &  - 4138 & 917 &  - 4721 \\ 
 - 4138 & 7934 &  - 4717 & 921 \\ 
917 &  - 4717 & 6000 &  - 2200 \\ 
 - 4721 & 921 &  - 2200 & 6000 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2069 }{ 3971 }  &  \frac{ 3060867 }{ 11472196 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 8416967 }{ 11472196 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
7942 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 22944392 }{ 3971 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7984289425 }{ 2868049 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2069 }{ 3971 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 917 }{ 7942 }  &  -  \frac{ 8416967 }{ 11472196 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 4721 }{ 7942 }  &  -  \frac{ 3055229 }{ 11472196 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
7942 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 22944392 }{ 3971 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7984289425 }{ 2868049 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2069 }{ 3971 }  &  \frac{ 917 }{ 7942 }  &  -  \frac{ 4721 }{ 7942 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 8416967 }{ 11472196 }  &  -  \frac{ 3055229 }{ 11472196 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
7942 &  - 4138 & 917 &  - 4721 \\ 
 - 4138 & 7934 &  - 4717 & 921 \\ 
917 &  - 4717 & 6000 &  - 2200 \\ 
 - 4721 & 921 &  - 2200 & 6000 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc $$

Comment: It is a nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: I was supposed to make a bounty but you did it, what a chance.